# How to use JavaScript and vb.net variables in asp drop down menu queries

Tags: javascript, vb.net, drop-down-menu, asp-classic, visual-studio-2005

I'm using visual studio 2005 with vb.net. I have a little problem with a drop down menu in my aspx.

This is the connection and query code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="OraCboPro" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyORACLECON %>"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyORACLECON.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand=" select distinct PROPINSI from cs_site_lang_kdpos_v  where kodecab = '(my variabel)' ">
```

The query requires a value from a session variable from aspx.vb or a global variable in my JavaScript in my aspx. How can i do pass this in to the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on drop down menu:

```
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)Login1.LoginView.FindControl("ddlDomain");
```